# Zero-width RegEx does not match in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am studying the zero-width RegEx. First, I test my pattern and text at http://testregex.com/ and it works well. Then I test them in my Java program, but they don't match. So I'd like to make it clear the cause of problem. Any reply would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
pattern:`\w*(?=ing)`
```

> text:`I’m singing while you’re dancing`

Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RegexDemo demo = new RegexDemo();
    System.out.printf("%b%n", demo.zeroWidthAssertionEarly());
  }

  public boolean zeroWidthAssertionEarly()  
  {  
    String reg="\\w*(?=ing)";
    String word = "I’m singing while you’re dancing";
    boolean tem=false;  

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);  

    tem = matcher.matches(); 

    return tem;  
  } 
}
```

---

Thank you in advance. Now I hope I do better understand the difference between `match()` and `find()`, and I modified my code as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RegexDemo demo = new RegexDemo();
    System.out.printf("%b%n", demo.zeroWidthAssertionEarly());
  }

  public boolean zeroWidthAssertionEarly()  
  {  
    //匹配以ing结尾的单词
    String reg="\\w*(?=ing)";
    String word = "I’m singing while you’re dancing";//
    boolean tem=false;  

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);  

    while(matcher.find()){
      System.out.printf("start = %d%n", matcher.start());
      System.out.printf("end = %d%n", matcher.end());
    }        
    return tem;  
  } 
}
```

Its output confused me:

```
start = 4
end = 8
start = 8
end = 8
start = 25
end = 29
start = 29
end = 29
false
```

So my new question is: Why the output is not as follows?

```
start = 4
end = 8
start = 25
end = 29
false
```

Comment: `matches()` requires a full string match. Try `find()`. BTW, you have not indicated what you need to get as a result. Just true or false?

Comment: Your help is very useful,thanks a lot! I have read some related answers and have some understand of find().But I encounter a new problem if find() and start()/end().Can you give me some prompt again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your updated question is: use

```
String reg="(?U)\\w+(?=ing\\b)";
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/0MjKL7)

Explanation of the pattern:

- `\w+` - match **1 or more** alphanumeric or inderscore characters that are
- `(?=ing\b)` - followed by `ing` + a trailing word boundary.

The `(?U)` is necessary to make sure the word boundary works alright with Unicode strings.

Your pattern does not check if `ing` is located at the end of the word, and it allows matching `ing` at the beginning of a word which is not what you are after (I guess, matching `-ing` forms).

Comment: I see the reason.In my code, the "\w*" match 0 or more characters, so the "ing" matches itself.Get the usage of "?U",exciting!Thank you again :P